# My Jqgrid doesn't allow more than 15 rows while it can take 25 rows. Can you tel where I am doing the mistake

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqgrid

[image: Jqgrid not allowing more than 15 rows]

Below is my code part. I have changed the rowNum to 9999,10000 ..but nothing works.

```
            height: 550,
            loadonce:true,
            rowNum: 10000,
            rowList: [20, 30, 50],
            sortable: true,
            sortname: 'num',
            sortorder: "asc",
            pager: pager_id
```

Comment: Could your reproduce it in a plunker ?

Comment: You can't use multiple columns with the same column name! See `name: 'id'`. The values of `name` column should be unique and corresponds to restrictions of `id` attribute of HTML (no spaces for example). If you have problems with **the filling of data** in jqGrid then you should include the test data (more as 15 rows). You should always write which version and which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It would be very good to provide the demo (in JSFiddle).

Comment: By the way if you fill the grid with `15` rows, but you use `rowNum: 10000` then only 15 rows will be displayed. I suppose that you load the data from the server (`datatype: "json"`). jqGrid send `rows` parameter with the value from `rowNum` to the server, but I suppose that the server code ignored the value and use fixed value 15 as the size of the page. One see `View 1-15 of 52` at the right side of the bottom pager of the grid. If means typically that the response from the server contains `{"total": 4, "page": 1, "records": 52, "rows" : [...]}` where `rows` array contains only 15 items.